# “operation not supported” when invoking an RPC call on Windows 2008

Tags: c++, windows, windows-server-2008, rpc, midl

The application uses Microsoft RPC for interprocess communications. The application works flawlessly on Windows Server 2003 (Server WS2003 or WS 2008 --- Client WS2003). But the application fails when the client is on Windows Server 2008.

Here is the flow of client part

RpcStringBindingCompose(.....)
RpcBindingFromStringBinding(.....)
RpcMgmtIsServerListening(....) //This method returns success even on WS2008

After this whenever i call a method rpcMethod(...) defined in IDL file (code generated using MIDL compiler 6.00.0366), it thorws an exception (Error Code 1764) "Operation is not Supported".
The MIDL-generated stub redirects to NdrClientCall2() which throws this exception.

Similar issue reported here: [Operation is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750903/operation-is-not-supported-when-invoking-an-rpc-call-on-vista)

Comment: What's the IDL definition of the failing method?

Comment: void RemoteGetU2UMachines([in,size_is(localSize2)] wchar_t instanceID[], [in] short localSize2, [in] short nMaxMachines, [out,size_is(nMaxMachines)] long Machines[], [out] short *nMachines);

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/05/27/ndrclientcall2-fails-with-rpc-s-already-listening-when-using-pipes-over-ncalrpc.aspx

Comment: @Hans Passant: The OP doesn't seem to have pipes in his method.

Comment: the error im getting is "RPC_S_CANNOT_SUPPORT" & yes @sharptooth there are no pipes.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the method, it has everything to do with how RPC connects.

Comment: @Hans Passant: ncalrpc is only not supported when a method uses synchronous pipes, otherwise it is still supported.